# Powershell Switch parameter accepting argument

Tags: powershell

How can I make $m switch accept one argument but $prebuild doesn't need any argument.

```
Param (
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
 [Switch]$m,
 [Switch]$prebuild
)
```

The script would be executed as below but I get the following error.

```
.\test.ps1 -m java
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'java'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `$m` to a `[string]`:

```
param(
  [string]$m,
  [switch]$prebuild
)
```

To test whether an argument was passed by the caller, use the `$PSBoundParameters` automatic variable:

```
if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('m')){
  # An argument was passed to `-m`
}
```

(This last part is unnecessary if you keep the `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]` attribute)